# fetch reports invalid_arg_type when using nodejs fetch and form-data

Tags: node.js, fetch, form-data

Can anybody tells me what I'm doing wrong here ? I'm using:
node v14.17.3 / node-fetch / form-data 4.0.0
my code looks like:

```
let
        finalUrl = _transactionUrl.upload.url.replace('<transactionID>', _transactionID),
        fd = new FormData(),
        rc = 0;

    fd.append('file', fs.createReadStream(p_fileName), { filename: p_fileName, contentType: 'application/octet-stream', mimeType: 'application/octet-stream' });
    fd.append('id', _transactionID);
    fd.append('url', '');
    // (...)

    const
        headers = Object.assign({ Authorization: _authBase64 }, fd.getHeaders()),
        fetchOptions = {
            method: _transactionUrl.upload.method,  // POST in this case
            headers: headers,
            body: fd,
        }; console.dir(fetchOptions);
        
    log(_dashLine, `fetching now: [${finalUrl}]`);
    let
        rsp         = await fetch(finalUrl, fetchOptions);
        rspText = await rsp.text(); log(rspText);
```

the fetchOptions object looks OK to me...

```
{
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Basic ZHVtYXNkZW5pcy10ZXN0OkRvY2Fwb3N0ZTIwMjEh',
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------361340234590893974776762'
  },
  body: FormData {
    _overheadLength: 1335,
    _valueLength: 38,
    _valuesToMeasure: [ [ReadStream] ],
    writable: false,
    readable: true,
    dataSize: 0,
    maxDataSize: 2097152,
    pauseStreams: true,
    _released: false,
    _streams: [
      '----------------------------361340234590893974776762\r\n' +
        'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="contratdemo.pdf"\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      [DelayedStream],
      [Function: bound ],
    _currentStream: null,
    _insideLoop: false,
    _pendingNext: false,
    _boundary: '--------------------------361340234590893974776762'
  }
}

---------------- fetching now: [https://FQDN masked]/api/v2/transactions/2c96ad2c7ae1cbbe017ae9400f530a8b/document?requestReference=]
```

`

but fetch throws this error:

`
_http_outgoing.js:722
throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('first argument',
^

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received type boolean (false)
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:722:11)
    at ClientRequest.write (_http_outgoing.js:687:15)
    at FormData.ondata (internal/streams/legacy.js:20:31)
    at FormData.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at FormData.CombinedStream.write (C:\Users\ddumas\Documents\node\node_modules\combined-stream\lib\combined_stream.js:138:8)
    at FormData.CombinedStream._pipeNext (C:\Users\ddumas\Documents\node\node_modules\combined-stream\lib\combined_stream.js:126:8)
    at FormData.CombinedStream._realGetNext (C:\Users\ddumas\Documents\node\node_modules\combined-stream\lib\combined_stream.js:99:10)
    at FormData.CombinedStream._getNext (C:\Users\ddumas\Documents\node\node_modules\combined-stream\lib\combined_stream.js:82:12)
    at DelayedStream.emit (events.js:387:35)
    at DelayedStream._handleEmit (C:\Users\ddumas\Documents\node\node_modules\delayed-stream\lib\delayed_stream.js:82:15) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Anybody sees what I'm doing wrong on this ?
Thanks a lot for help,

Denys

Comment: forgot to say:  the file passed in argument as p_fileName is a binary (pdf file). Thanks

Comment: FYI, working fine with multi-part.